Should there be a new tag for skydiving canopies?
Skydiving canopies are ram air parafoils similar to paragliders. Should we add a tag for them?
Why not use the existing "canopy"?
Unfortunately, the tag "canopy" seems to already be taken to refer to an enclosure over the cockpit.
Why not use the existing "parachute"?
They are often called "parachutes". However, the word parachute technically refers to the drag-only type (e.g. a round piece of fabric) rather than something with an airfoil. It would be nice to distinguish the two.
Why not use the existing "skydiving"?
This tag might work. However, it seems too broad.
It seems strange to me that questions about freefall would have the same tag as questions about the canopy flight.
How about "canopy-piloting"?
Canopy piloting is a discipline in skydiving that focuses on the skills of piloting the canopy. Participants don't even bother with freefall and deploy the canopy soon after exiting the plane.
There are national and worldwide competitions for it, and this is a widely used term.
However, there are two other canopy disciplines that also have their own names: "classic accuracy" and "canopy formations".
So, this might be too specific.
How about "skydiving-canopy"?
I like this one. It would pop up when people type in either "skydiving" or "canopy" and would be easily found.
Example questions that could use the tag:

Why/how is a downplane parachute configuration aerodynamically stable?
Does partial flow separation due to toggle input affect the physics of paraglider/ canopy controls?
Why would a ram air parachute need less brake input to stall at a higher altitude?

Thoughts?
